# What is the name of this programming language feature and are there any real-world languages that support it?

Tags: programming-languages, pseudocode, language-theory

Let a tree data structure be defined as such:

A tree has one Node as its root. A Node is either a Leaf or it is an Inner Node which has one or more Nodes as its children.

In some kind of pseudo OO programming language we may define a tree like this:

```
Node := InnerNode | Leaf

Leaf {

    isLeaf() : TRUE

}

InnerNode {

    isLeaf() : FALSE
    children() : List<Node>

}

Tree {
    root() : Node
}
```

Now we can define two functions, 'bad_code' and 'good_code'. The function 'bad_code' does not compile, the other function does:

```
function bad_code(Node anyNode) : void {

    // this will give a compile time error "type Node does not define method children()"
    anyNode.children();
}

function good_code(Node anyNode) : void {

    // the compiler understands that all Nodes must have a method called isLeaf() which 
    // returns a boolean
    let b : boolean <- anyNode.isLeaf();

    if (b == FALSE) {

        // this will not give a compile time error because the compiler can deduce that 
        // anyNode must be of type InnerNode which has the method children()
        anyNode.children();
    }
}
```

Question:

1. Is the above an example of a language feature that has been defined / described in some official way?
2. If so: what is this language feature officially called?
3. Are there any real-world programming languages which implement this language feature?
4. Can this language feature be implemented as a compile time check with zero costs at runtime?

Comment: It's a very verbose syntax for something that pattern matching and algebraic data types do much cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is that the compiler uses the control-flow graph to narrow the type of a variable, so that when an `if` statement tests a condition which relates to the type of a variable, a more specific type for the same variable can be inferred for the body of the `if` statement.

This is called *control-flow type narrowing*, and it's done in e.g. [Typescript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript). It is purely a static check, done at compile-time with no runtime penalty; in fact, types in Typescript are not available at runtime at all.

```js
type TreeNode = InnerNode | Leaf

interface Leaf {
    isLeaf: true
}

interface InnerNode {
    isLeaf: false
    children: Node[]
}

function bad_code(anyNode: TreeNode): void {
    // type error: Property 'children' does not exist on type 'TreeNode'.
    console.log(anyNode.children);
}

function good_code(anyNode: TreeNode): void {
    if (!anyNode.isLeaf) {
        // narrowed type to anyNode: InnerNode
        console.log(anyNode.children);
    }
}
```

Note that Typescript requires you to do this in a particular way; we test `anyNode.isLeaf` directly rather than storing it in a variable `b: boolean` first, because Typescript doesn't keep track of the relationship between the two variables `b` and `anyNode`:

```js
function bad_in_typescript(anyNode: TreeNode): void {
    let b: boolean = anyNode.isLeaf;

    if (!b) {
        // type error: Property 'children' does not exist on type 'TreeNode'.
        console.log(anyNode.children);
    }
}
```

Also, in the above code `isLeaf` is a property instead of a method. Typescript does have a related feature called *user-defined type guards* which allow a method's return type to be something like `this is Leaf`, indicating that the method returns `true` only when called on something of type `Leaf`:

```js
type TreeNode = InnerNode | Leaf

interface BaseNode {
    isLeaf(): this is Leaf
    isInner(): this is InnerNode
}

interface Leaf extends BaseNode {}

interface InnerNode extends BaseNode {
    children(): Node[]
}
```

However, Typescript is still a bit more limited than your example; we have to test `anyNode.isInner()` because `!anyNode.isLeaf()` won't necessarily do the same narrowing. (Typescript uses structural types, so in fact this `Leaf` is a supertype of `InnerNode`, which causes some problems for the union type. If you give `Leaf` a property like `value: number` which `InnerNode` doesn't have, then `!anyNode.isLeaf()` works how you would expect.)

- [Typescript Playground Link for version with properties](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgThCA5A9gE2gXigSQHZ4RyoZQA+UAMhAIYBmAUAwJZ7BF00DG019UAbwZQRUZgGc+dAFxRgcAK4QGAXyat2cTj1wEiJaENFjJtGVE4AbccuNcAFs0toEeWQYDaAXVVM6CvC5gZhQ8KAAjGjQAfS50CAAKGjwQA1l4RAMASlkANxRmNEFhUQB6UrlwaCI4FDhZAAVayDhQKAByBycXCDx2qDQUCHEoPBRgKAgADwkJ0MrIDozkePaAOhKROLxxFEsINcsUAHMklIM1rudXLIBuXwZ-QOD545R0WPiz1Pj0hBWMDkoPlCsVjMw6FAEgBCZI-DBrCRSLJg4xlCp4GhwWoAdwgRVAi2AKCgcLSukIxHimzR212+0OJ2+FyuPTwdxpajUjwCQRCYUiMVY0UJwy4cGYYGAzN+sH+2TyBSKRlE+wm4Vk4Xe+2SUGwZPiiNM9HuNIhUOh4RRKrRUHKo3GoyxuPxABoIhAuDQFDY5PZoHEALZgJxEAZDcR9CbybgAa1JUAQlhoLx2jjANOM9vCEGAeN6EXaI1FpLwRQNGCLC1stqgdL2ByOpwrB1ZN3uxi5DCAA)
- [Typescript Playground Link for version with methods](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgThCA5A9gE2gXigSQHZ4RyoZQA+UAMhAIYBmAUAwJZ7BF00DG0AQjQGdk6aAG8GUSVGYDq9ABQBKAFxRgACxnSBVWoynb8hOEtUatWo0RIQGAXyat2cTj130oEAB7s8aHfxCNlCiDixsHNzQVsQinj4QfgGCwqTiBlyaADZoCHimUDYA2gC69kx0AK54XMDMKHhQAEY0aAD6XCLyNHggNqrwiDYqUABuKMxoIRJSAPSzauDQRHAocKoACquQcKBQAOSZzDl5+1BoKBA6eCjA8TJ3DYuQB4OpEPsAdDOSnXgCKCyEE+WRQAHNur0bJ8jidEkpFABucoMKo1OpPMEodAdLo9PoiAYId4jcaTaYGZh0KCQgkYT4yGIIikGOYLPA0OCrADuECmoBewBQUHx-VwBGsIh+rL+AKBIPBtOhsNy8MUSOlDjCaNq9UaLXarDaAquXDgzDAwCVhNgxOGqjJU3SUipNIAhKKRAzZHpmc7WVB5s9lly1pttkQ9odsqq8GcLlcoDc7t4HlAniaDoRRkQvtKMg05cDQRDPfSVXkEciDFqGEA)